# String format of sharedPreferences

Tags: android

I am trying to modify the following code:

```
dictName = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFERENCES_DICT_NAME, null);
if (dictName == null) {
}
```

My situation is I know dictName is not null and its value is "something". So I modified the code into:

```
dictName = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFERENCES_DICT_NAME, null);
if (dictName == "something") {
}
```

However, I can't get my code work. So I am wondering is it correct for me to put dictName =="something"?

Comment: Compare `Strings` using `equals(String)` method, not `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `String.equals("something")` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase("something")`
This will do the thing and it will be fast.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to write sharedPreferences. Anyway, thanks for the reply.